# How to show image on background color buddyboss login/register page

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, buddypress

I have a child theme of buddyboss. And I have style.css file.

And it is about the register/ login page

What I want to archive is the following image:

[image]

So I have this code:

```
/**
 * For register page
 */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body.buddypress.register.login-split-page .login-split .split-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #270A4C !important;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;

  }
}

/**
 * for login page
 */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body.login.login-split-page .login-split .split-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #270A4C !important;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/**
 * background image
 */
.login-split {
  background-image: url(./wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/bg-mycells.png);
  background-size: covers;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-color: #270A4C !important;

}
```

But the purple color on the login page doesn't even show.

So what I have to change?

The CSS class in dev tools looks like this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
body.login.login-split-page .login-split {
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

This is how it looks now:

[image]

So in dev tools, I do this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
body.login.login-split-page .login-split {
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

And I see the red color.

But if I do this in style.css:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
body.login.login-split-page .login-split {
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

And I reload the page, the red color is not visible.

I just don't understand. the page register ads the purple color.

But even when I go to: E:\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\buddyboss-theme-child\assets\css

And I modify the file: custom.css:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
This is your custom stylesheet.

Add your own styles here to make theme updates easier.
To override any styles from other stylesheets, simply copy them into here and edit away.

Make sure to respect the media queries! Otherwise you may
accidentally add desktop styles to the mobile layout.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
--------------------------------------------------------------*/


body.login.login-split-page .login-split .split-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, #3204fdba, #9907facc), url(./wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/bg-mycells.png);
```

Comment: Thank you. But then I only see the color and not the image

Comment: This is strange. I did it in codepen and it worked just fine
here's the link: https://codepen.io/edoardo-balducci/pen/MWOqzZw

Comment: But do you know buddyboss? Wordpress?   how the css looks like then?

Comment: @media (min-width: 992px) {
  body.buddypress.register.login-split-page .login-split .split-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #270A4C !important;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #3204fdba, #9907facc), url(./wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/bg-mycells.png);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;

  }
}

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: This is my childTheme: https://github.com/savantKing/wordpress